# Send SMS from PC through Bluetooth

Tags: sms, bluetooth

I have an HTC Amaze with Android 2.3.

Is any way I can send and receive messages on my PC via Bluetooth to my phone? I tried to connect with MyPhoneExplorer app, but its does not support HTC Amaze.

Comment: Related: [Is there a SMS to bluetooth router app?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14842)

Comment: KDE Connect is marvelous for this and many more purposes, because you can simply share any text via the clipboard, even between phones directly! I marvel again and again at how it *just works*...

Answer (score 1):

Remote Phone Call is much more polished for SMS to PC.

https://www.justremotephone.com/

[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1):

If you're a gamer at all, you might be interested in using something like Razor Comms!
http://www.razerzone.com/comms

It is a free VoIP program created by Razor that will give you an ingame overlay of your communications, including your phone. It also can do this out of game. It has a call forwarding and SMS forwarding feature that will allow you to answer calls and respond to text messages while on the computer. Even if you're not into games, the VoIP still works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I former times I have used [MyPhoneExplorer](http://www.fjsoft.at/) application. It was initially released for SonyEricsson but later added android support.

You can stablish a bluetooth connection between this app and your phone.

Website: http://www.fjsoft.at/

Comment: I have HTC Amaze and this device does not support it. Is there any other application.

Comment: You can ask at their forum too: http://www.fjsoft.at/forum/viewtopic.php?t=12336 because I see other HTC devices working there.

Comment: Everything is Ok, but when it is connecting through Bluetooth its stops on detecting phone model. it means it does not support HTC Amaze. Also it is not in the list.